# What's the meaning of mutation in React Documentation?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

```
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ul>
```

> React will match the two **first** trees, match the two **second** trees, and
>   then insert the **third** tree.

```
<ul>
  <li>Duke</li>
  <li>Villanova</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Connecticut</li>
  <li>Duke</li>
  <li>Villanova</li>
</ul>
```

> React will mutate every child instead of realizing it can keep the
>   **Duke** and **Villanova** subtrees intact. This
>   inefficiency can be a problem.

I'm having hard time understanding what they mean by the phrase "React will mutate every child".

This can be found from their website: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children

Comment: Mutate as in "change".

Comment: Does that mean that they will create an entirely new tree every time a new child-element is found from that second tree?

Comment: The docs are just saying that when you preserve order, the reconciliation algorithm can quickly insert or remove a child after the last child (thus a quicker DOM update). But if you don't preserve order and insert it from the beginning, React must then go through each of the new children and reinsert them into the updated DOM.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. In the second case it will have to go through every element and add it to the new tree because it was not added in the end of the list. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Note that React provides keys to mediate this. Keys allow React to know which one was inserted instead of having to reinsert every child because it doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your first example, the existing items in the list `first` & `second` don't change position. They remain the 1st and 2nd items in the list when the 3rd item is added. React recognises this and leaves the first two items alone, and adds a first one.

In the second example, `Duke` and `Villanova` change positions from 1st and 2nd, to be 2nd and 3rd respectively. React doesn't know that you have just added an item at the beginning. It thinks all 3 items are new, and so removes all 3 items, and re-renders them. This can be costly and time consuming if you have a long list.

This is why unique [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys)s are important.

Comment: In addition to this : why setting **unique keys** is important, because : "If the key is an index, moving an item changes it. As a result, component state for things like controlled inputs can get mixed up and updated in unexpected ways."

Answer (score 2):

If you have attempted to render an array data using

```
array.map()
```

You will notice react will demand you provide a key for each element of the array. What react do is track each member of your data belonging a parent, such that when you delete or add more data, react knows how to adjust efficiently. If not, changes in your data will be taken as mutation and rendered as new set of data which can be a problem especially as your data grows.